# Alt+Shift change of language lag since Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, keyboard-shortcuts, windows-11, lag, input-languages

This has been a longstanding problem ever since Windows 10 for me. There is a noticeable delay between pressing the key combination and the actual change of language. I often press the keys, start writing and the change is not reflected and wrong characters are typed due to the language not being changed. I've noticed this several years ago immediately after switching from Windows 7 and 8 after that. I've tried searching for this a couple of times in the past with no resolution.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Switching input language in Windows 10 is not always instant](https://superuser.com/questions/1361328/switching-input-language-in-windows-10-is-not-always-instant)